# concatenating 2 columns based on multiple conditions using jolt spec

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to concatenate the two columns based on the below conditions.

Input:
[
{
"A": "M-L",
"B": "S-L"
}
]

[
{
"A": "",
"B": "S-L"
}
]

[
{
"A": "M-L",
"B": ""
}
]

[
{
"A": "",
"B": ""
}
]

and I want output as below .

C="M-L,S-L" C="S-L" C="M-L" C=""

I have tried the below code but else part is not working .

[
{
"operation": "modify-default-beta",
"spec": {
"C": "=concat(@(1,A),',',@(1,B))",
"ASize": "=size(@(1,A))",
"BSize": "=size(@(1,B))"
}
},
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"ASize": {
"0": {
"@2,B": "merchant_Planned_Size_Range"
},
"*": {
"BSize": {
"0": {
"@2,A": "merchant_Planned_Size_Range"
},
"*": {
"@2,C": "merchant_Planned_Size_Range"
}
}
}
}
}
}
]

Comment: Are you sure that the non-else return some non-null result ?

Comment: Why the third expected result is `C="M-L"` instead of `C="S-L"`, and if so why do you need a conditional ? That seems unclear ...